# Compare differences between MATLAB and python images from the same data

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am ploting the same values in python and in MATLAB ( [The data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_uM07OVC9eoOVBnUGhzWWNCUUU/view?usp=sharing) is exactly the same).

just doing

```
import scipy.io as sio
zzz = sio.loadmat(pathToData)
plot(zzz['zzz'][:,0]) #python
```

In matlab

```
plot(zzz)        %matlab
```

I am trying to get **`matplotlib`** to create an image that looks the same as MATLAB figure, like [**this example**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_uM07OVC9eoeVRSNGpYR0t2ZU0/view?usp=sharing).

- The following images where created with screen capture so to avoid any post processing of the image. I made sure both of the figures are in the same size. then I put one next to the other and created a screencapture of them both at the same time

I also put the lines one next to the other:
[image]

[image]

It is a bit hard to see but the MATLAB image is much more noisy and it looks like the python image is after a moving average of something like this ( especially in the start of plot)

Do you have **any advice of how to make** the python figure look **exactly** like the MATLAB one?

( I uploaded [**`the data`**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_uM07OVC9eoOVBnUGhzWWNCUUU/view?usp=sharing) if anyone interested in some experiments )

**EDIT**

I tried to do antialiased = False, the results are a bit better, but the linewidth is bigger no matter how small I try to do it ([original screencapture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_uM07OVC9eobWVBR3RDU2FUOGc&authuser=0) )

[image]

Comment: Could you include the full code (including loading of mat file into python)? I am sure many experienced python programmers would otherwise skip this question because they have no idea how to deal with a matlab specific file format.

Comment: Assuming, you have stated, the pieces of **`data`** ( `== zzz` ) **are the same**, so the data-processing-**phase** is the point where to start from. However, **if** the `zzz` inputs are not the same for MATLAB / python processing, check rather the data-generation-**phase** for any difference(s). You may also plot difference between the pair of zzz-datapoints ( one from MATLAB the other from python data-source ) **to get more important details**, better readable than from observing just the zoomed-in pixelised-GUI representations )

Comment: Could it be that the python line is just thicker?

Comment: Uhm... How do you superimpose the two figures?! Is there any scaling involved? And do you compare screenshots or figures saved to disk?

Comment: @hitzg it is a screen shot of both of the images at the same time. no scaling not post-processing.

Comment: Yes, and then after that you use some image processing software to overlay one over the other, right? In the figure you posted there seems to be some difference in scale. At least on the y axis. In other words, the shape of the lines does not match perfectly

Comment: Only half joking: why bother? Anti-aliased pictures usually look better, so why are you trying to make a nice Matplotlib graph as ugly as a Matlab one? A more interesting question would be how to get Matlab to use anti-aliasing by default :)

Comment: btw: your link to the original sceenshot does not work

Comment: @BasSwinckels I am doing whats called exponential peeling, and it is easier to do it on the matlab figure ( it is more informative)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is due to the fact that matplotlib uses [anti aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) when producing the figure. However, this is an artist property which you can set:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 500)

plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='with anti-aliasing')
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), antialiased=False, label='without anti-aliasing')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Zoom on top left corner:

[image]

So by switching off the anti-aliasing filter you might get very similar results to the Matlab version.

Comment: Regarding the linewidth: You specify the linewidth in points. When you save it to a png, the resulting linewidth depends on the dpi (dots per inch) setting of your figure.

Comment: I do not save to png, I do screencapture ( so to avoid post processing of the image). it is screen capture of the 2 figures at the same time...

Comment: Well on screen (not in a saved file), a line can't really be thinner than 1 pixel. Otherwise you would not see it.

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure if it is possible to create the exact same plot. Even though matplotlib was inspired by Matlab, you are comparing two very different software packages.

Comment: Chances are, the DPIs are also different. Are you setting them to be the same as well?